# Rejecting minor edits - already accepted

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review

While reviewing suggested edits, I often reject edits as "minor", e.g. fixing one spelling mistake, removing "thanks" at the end, etc.  From reading other posts on meta, I see that I'm not alone in this.  However it always takes longer to reject an edit than to approve it (one button hit for approve vs. button click, selection, another button click for reject).  As a result, quite often by the time I select "too minor" and hit "reject", I get message "This edit has already been approved".  In quite a few cases, when I click initial "reject", I can see already two other rejections, yet by the time I "reject", the edit is approved.  Looking through some of these approved edits, they are usually approved by users with lower rep (barely over 2K).

There is a lot of discussion here on meta about what to do with minor edits, minor editors, etc., however I'm concerned with what to do about serial minor edit approvers.  Is there a way to flag edits/users/etc. somehow to indicate that they are abusing the review system?

**EDIT:** Here is an [example question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/951713).  The edit is certainly minor and two people with higher rep have rejected it.  Unfortunately it was then approved by lower-rep users before I had a chance to reject it.

Comment: No, there isn't a way to flag review actions.

Comment: @YannisRizos It's a shame though...

Comment: what about increasing the rep needed to review suggested edits?

Comment: I agree that with the new review system, badge hunters and rep hunters it's looking more and more like the wild wild west rather than professional mechanism to help improve the contents. Those who draw first, win.

Comment: Strongly related, maybe duplicate: [The current review system encourages fake reviews; some people upvote everything rather than actually fixing problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-fake-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything?lq=1)

Comment: The edit was accepted because someone of higher rep improved the edit, but left the 'helpful' checkbox selected. I certainly would have unchecked that box.